# Create JComboBox and assign data later

Tags: java, swing, awt

Hi I am trying to create a JComboBox using Java Swing.

By the time the JCombobox is created, the contents of this box is not decided. Therefore I cannot use the constructor:

```
String[] selectionArray = {........};
JComboBox myComboBox = new JComboBox(selectionArray);
```

I want to assign the data (an array of Strings) later after I created the JComboBox.

I looked around the API and didn't find a corresponding method to do this.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look for [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) and [JComboBox.setModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setModel%28javax.swing.ComboBoxModel%29) method.